# Create New DataFrame, assigning a count for each instance in a time frame

Tags: python, pandas

Below is script for a simplified version of the df in question:

```
plan_dates=pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-01-05'],
                         'end_date':  ['2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-02-03','2021-03-04','2021-03-05']})

plan_dates

    start_date   end_date
0   2021-01-01  2021-01-03
1   2021-01-02  2021-01-04
2   2021-01-03  2021-02-03
3   2021-01-04  2021-03-04
4   2021-01-05  2021-03-05
```

I would like to create a new DataFrame which has 2 columns:

- **date**
- **count of active plans** (the count of cases where the date is within the `start_date` & `end_date` in each row of the `plan_dates` df)

INTENDED DF:

```
    date        count_active_plans
0   2021-01-01         1
1   2021-01-02         2
2   2021-01-03         3
3   2021-01-04         3
4   2021-01-05         3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert both columns to datetimes and add one day to `end_date`, then repeat index by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with subtraction of days and add counter values by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), last count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with come data cleaning and converting to `DataFrame`:

```
plan_dates['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(plan_dates['start_date'])
plan_dates['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(plan_dates['end_date']) + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')

s = plan_dates['end_date'].sub(plan_dates['start_date']).dt.days
df = plan_dates.loc[plan_dates.index.repeat(s)].copy()
counter = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df1 = (df['start_date'].add(pd.to_timedelta(counter, unit='d'))
                       .value_counts()
                       .sort_index()
                       .rename_axis('date')
                       .reset_index(name='count_active_plans'))
print (df1)
         date  count_active_plans
0  2021-01-01                   1
1  2021-01-02                   2
2  2021-01-03                   3
3  2021-01-04                   3
4  2021-01-05                   3
..        ...                 ...
59 2021-03-01                   2
60 2021-03-02                   2
61 2021-03-03                   2
62 2021-03-04                   2
63 2021-03-05                   1

[64 rows x 2 columns]
```